# Can't see a mistake in my proof, monic composition and monicity of it's composites.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, category-theory

Assume that $(n \circ m)$ is monic and $\exists g_1, g2: (n \circ m) \circ g_1 = (n \circ m) \circ g_2$, then by the monic's definition:
$$g_1 = g_2$$
Lemma: $\forall f, g_1, g_2: g_1 = g_2 \implies f \circ g_1 = f \circ g_2$.
By the given lemma:
$$g_1 = g_2 \implies (m \circ g_1) = (m \circ g_2)$$ 
Brought all together:
$$(n \circ m) \circ g_1 = (n \circ m) \circ g_2 = n \circ (m \circ g_1) = n \circ (m \circ g_2) \implies$$ 
$$g_1 = g_2 \implies$$ 
$$(m \circ g_1) = (m \circ g_2)$$
Thus, $n$ is left-cancellabe (monic).

I know that this isn't true and there are many examples when $(n \circ m)$ is monic and $m$ is monic, althought $n$ isn't. But I fail to discover a mistake in the proof above...

Comment: You proved that $n$ is left cancellable only for maps of the form $m\circ k$, but there are many maps that aren't $m\circ k$ for any $k$